# Automated and scalable approach to store each dictionary item into class (instance) attributes with same keys and values?

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, oop, input

I have a dictionary `input_dict={'foo1':3, 'foo2':6}` and I want to store its contents in an instance of class `matClass` such that `mat.foo1=3`, `mat.foo2=6`, etc...

I need this process to be automated since the dictionary may change in size depending on user inputs.

The code below iterates through the dictionary items and uses `setattr` to iteratively create class attributes with the same key and value as the dictionary. The `if` statement is there to check that the variables inputted by the user are actually supported by the rest of the code.

```
input_dict = {'foo1':3, 'foo2':6}

class matClass:
    allowed_input = ['foo1', 'foo2']

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def import_data(self, input_dict):
        if set(list(input_dict.keys())).issubset(self.allowed_input):
            for key, value in input_dict.items():
                setattr(self, key, value)

mat = matClass()
mat.import_data(input_dict)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Are there hidden dangers to this approach?

I am not necessarily bound to dictionaries, I could use dataframes if more convenient.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't create a dictionary as a class attribute instead? Seems like it would be easier that way.

Comment: That's not runnable Python code

Comment: @DarkKnight, sorry about that, edited the question to make it runnable

Comment: Why not just take a copy of input_dict as an instance attribute? Or create a new (instance) dictionary that contains valid key/value pairs. Setting attributes in the way you're doing it seems wholly unnecessary

Comment: @50Fifty, I thought about that but it somehow didn't feel "clean", since there would be an extra level of nesting to the data that's not really "necessary". The data is just user-input in an Excel file, so the user has freedom to remove some variables. I thought the cleanest approach for both users and programmers would be to still have a clear and definite list of instance attributes defined in the __init__, as well not having to fish inside dictionaries to use variables in the rest of the code.

Comment: @DarkKnight same answer above applied, additionally user-input in the Excel file will not be the only way data is created for this class, so in general I want to avoid adding too many data structures.

I edited my question to reflect that foo1 and foo2 should already be initialized in the __init__

Comment: @Carlo I propose just one data structure - a dictionary. It's a much cleaner approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want a limited subset of keys/values from the input dictionary.

So, why not create a dictionary to contain relevant data then override __getattr__ to access them?

Something like this:

```
from typing import Any


class matClass:
    ALLOWED = {'foo1', 'foo2'}
    def __init__(self):
        self._dict = dict()
        self.foo3 = 99
    def import_data(self, input_dict: dict):
        for key, value in input_dict.items():
            if key in matClass.ALLOWED:
                self._dict[key] = value
    def __getattr__(self, __name: str) -> Any:
        try:
            return self._dict[__name]
        except KeyError:
            return self.__getattribute__(__name)

_dict = {
    'foo1': 1,
    'foo2': 2,
    'foo3': 3
}

mc = matClass()

mc.import_data(_dict)

print(mc.foo1)
print(mc.foo2)
print(mc.foo3)
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
99
```

Comment: Very nice solution, but what if I also want to initialize the variables in the ```__init__``` statement? So for example:```self.foo1 = None``` and ```self.foo2 = None```?
In that case the ```__getattr__``` override would not work. Ideally I would still like to initialize the attributes...

Comment: I have modified the code to show how you could do that